# Not able to build libmupdf.so

Tags: android, cygwin, mupdf, pdf-viewer

I have been trying my luck on Mupdf since a couple of weeks but not able to build .so file.
I am simply trying " Make" on cygwin now, which i didn't tried earlier and wasted my time.

To build the so file for Mupdf, what i am doing is, just writing a simple command on cygwin terminal after importing all the major files required, cmd is: make -f Makefile.

Now all my files are getting build and linked one by one, except for two of the files. And the error I am getting is:

LINK build/debug/mupdf
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `winopen':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:127: undefined reference to`_XOpenDisplay'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:131: undefined reference to `_XInternAtom'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:132: undefined reference to`_XInternAtom'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:133: undefined reference to `_XInternAtom'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:134: undefined reference to`_XInternAtom'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:135: undefined reference to `_XInternAtom'
build/debug/x11_main.o:/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:136: more undefined references to`_XInternAtom' follow
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `winopen':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:142: undefined reference to`_XCreateFontCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:143: undefined reference to `_XCreateFontCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:144: undefined reference to`_XCreateFontCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:154: undefined reference to `_XAllocColor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:155: undefined reference to`_XAllocColor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:157: undefined reference to `_XCreateWindow'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:167: undefined reference to`_XSetWindowColormap'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:168: undefined reference to `_XSelectInput'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:174: undefined reference to`_XCreateGC'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:176: undefined reference to `_XDefineCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:178: undefined reference to`_XAllocWMHints'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:182: undefined reference to `_XCreateBitmapFromData'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:186: undefined reference to`_XCreateBitmapFromData'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:194: undefined reference to `_XSetWMHints'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:196: undefined reference to`_XFree'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:199: undefined reference to `_XAllocClassHint'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:204: undefined reference to`_XSetClassHint'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:205: undefined reference to `_XFree'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:208: undefined reference to`_XSetWMProtocols'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `wincursor':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:227: undefined reference to`_XDefineCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:229: undefined reference to `_XDefineCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:231: undefined reference to`_XDefineCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:232: undefined reference to `_XFlush'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function`wintitle':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:237: undefined reference to `_XStoreName'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:239: undefined reference to`_Xutf8SetWMProperties'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `winresize':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:260: undefined reference to`_XConfigureWindow'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:272: undefined reference to `_XMapWindow'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:273: undefined reference to`_XFlush'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:277: undefined reference to `_XNextEvent'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:287: undefined reference to`_XSetForeground'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:288: undefined reference to `_XFillRectangle'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:289: undefined reference to`_XFlush'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `winfullscreen':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:314: undefined reference to`_XSendEvent'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `fillrect':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:322: undefined reference to`_XFillRectangle'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `winblitsearch':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:331: undefined reference to`_XSetForeground'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `winblit':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:348: undefined reference to`_XSetForeground'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:354: undefined reference to `_XSetForeground'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function`windrawstringxor':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:432: undefined reference to `_XGetGCValues'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:435: undefined reference to`_XChangeGC'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:437: undefined reference to `_XSetForeground'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:439: undefined reference to`_XDrawString'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:440: undefined reference to `_XFlush'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:442: undefined reference to`_XGetGCValues'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:444: undefined reference to `_XChangeGC'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function`windrawstring':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:449: undefined reference to `_XSetForeground'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:450: undefined reference to`_XDrawString'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `windocopy':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:478: undefined reference to`_XSetSelectionOwner'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function `onselreq':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:506: undefined reference to`_XChangeProperty'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:513: undefined reference to `_XChangeProperty'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:520: undefined reference to`_XChangeProperty'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:530: undefined reference to `_XSendEvent'
build/debug/x11_main.o: In function`main':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:683: undefined reference to `_XNextEvent'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:704: undefined reference to`_XLookupString'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:681: undefined reference to `_XPending'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:800: undefined reference to`_XPending'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:842: undefined reference to `_XDestroyWindow'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:844: undefined reference to`_XFreePixmap'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:846: undefined reference to `_XFreeCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:847: undefined reference to`_XFreeCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:848: undefined reference to `_XFreeCursor'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:850: undefined reference to`_XFreeGC'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_main.c:852: undefined reference to `_XCloseDisplay'
build/debug/x11_image.o: In function`createximage':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:108: undefined reference to `_XShmQueryExtension'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:113: undefined reference to`_XShmCreateImage'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:139: undefined reference to `_XShmAttach'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:148: undefined reference to`_XSync'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:157: undefined reference to `_XCreateImage'
build/debug/x11_image.o: In function`make_colormap':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:194: undefined reference to `_XCreateColormap'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:198: undefined reference to`_XStoreColors'
build/debug/x11_image.o: In function `next_pool_image':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:307: undefined reference to`_XSync'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:309: undefined reference to `_XFlush'
build/debug/x11_image.o: In function`ximage_error_handler':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:322: undefined reference to `_XGetErrorText'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:328: undefined reference to`_XSetErrorHandler'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:329: undefined reference to `_XSetErrorHandler'
build/debug/x11_image.o: In function`ximage_init':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:351: undefined reference to `_XVisualIDFromVisual'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:352: undefined reference to`_XGetVisualInfo'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:355: undefined reference to `_XFree'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:359: undefined reference to`_XFree'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:362: undefined reference to `_XListPixmapFormats'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:369: undefined reference to`_XFree'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:382: undefined reference to `_XQueryExtension'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:383: undefined reference to`_XShmQueryExtension'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:387: undefined reference to `_XSetErrorHandler'
build/debug/x11_image.o: In function`ximage_blit':
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:452: undefined reference to `_XShmPutImage'
/cygdrive/d/Users/MOBDEV3/workspace1/Latest_Mupdf/jni/apps/x11_image.c:458: undefined reference to`_XPutImage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:146: recipe for target `build/debug/mupdf' failed
make: *** [build/debug/mupdf] Error 1

The problem is in "X11 Lib" as i see, but not able to do it.
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Make NOX11=yes works for me later on...

Comment: I guess you should accept my answer then! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try the make command with the argument For e.g,

make NOX11=yes